# How to get current Debian/Ubuntu version name in a Bash script

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt

How to get in a Bash script the simple lowercase name of the current Debian or Ubuntu release, e.g. stretch, jessie, xenial, artful?

Answer (score 7):

It's available in `/etc/os-release`, but it's inconsistent between Ubuntu and Debian. [Documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/systemd/os-release.5.en.html) isn't very specific on how to use it.

```
. /etc/os-release
NAME=$VERSION_CODENAME
if [ -z "$NAME" ]; then
    NAME=$(echo $VERSION | sed -rn 's|.+\((.+)\).+|\1|p')
fi
```

---

It's also available in the command `lsb_release`, which, when installed, needs no parsing:

```
NAME=$(lsb_release --codename --short)
```

---

Finally, it can be obtained directly from the sources file with some heavy-ish parsing.

```
NAME=$(sed -rn 's|^deb\s+\S+\s+(\w+)\s+main.*$|\1|p' /etc/apt/sources.list | head -n 1)
```

Comment: If you are going to use lsb_release, use the command like arguments to give you the code name, instead of grepping and slicing the output.  `NAME=$(lsb_release --codename --short)`.